# SFINAE and decltype(auto)

Tags: c++, auto, decltype, c++14

If a function template returns `decltype(auto)` (or another type specifier using `auto`) but the return statement would be ill-formed, does SFINAE result? Is the `return` statement considered to be the immediate context of the function signature?

Nothing in the N3690 draft seems to require this. By default, I guess SFINAE does not apply.

This seems unfortunate because you can write a function to forward to another function, but you cannot make its existence conditional on the delegate as when writing longhand. Furthermore, checking the existence of a peer nonstatic member function cannot be done without `decltype(auto)` because `this` cannot be used in a function signature. However this indicates a fundamental problem, as `decltype(auto)` provides a path to considering the class type as complete within a member signature, where it's not.

Has a proposal been written, or has the problem been formally analyzed anywhere?

The ability to treat the class type as complete within a member signature may have other implications… but that's just fodder for another question.

Comment: I had been wondering exactly this. Sadly, I've also been too lazy to follow 1y proposals...

Comment: @MarkGarcia Yes, that's a given. I just added a note to the end of the question; non-template members may still possibly open a wormhole to the twilight zone.

Comment: If there were some examples in the question, it would have been easier to understand for the stupids like me. :)

Comment: A little example would go a long way to make the question more clear. Perhaps there are other ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: @n.m. There are always more ways. I'm not stuck, but I am trying to avoid having 8 repetitive overloads. The answer I'm looking for is a pointer into a proposal paper, so I can tell whether to write a report myself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> but the return statement would be ill-formed, does SFINAE result?

The [proposal-n3638](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html) says,

> **SFINAE**
>
> Since the return type is deduced by instantiating the template, **if the instantiation is ill-formed, this causes an error rather than a substitution failure**. This allows an auto function to return a lambda, which is not possible using the decltype(returned expression) pattern.

Hope that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Bingo! Precisely what I was looking for. I need to go for now but I'll read that later to figure out how they reconcile member instantiation with incomplete type.

Answer (score 4):

Following up on Nawaz's link, the remaining questions are answered by N3690 §7.1.6.4/11:

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed.

This means that even if SFINAE worked with return type deduction, it couldn't be used to query one function declaration from another. The signature is essentially invalid until the `return` statement is processed, which occurs at the closing brace of the `class {}` definition, and after the definitions of preceding members have been processed.

In a sense, all member `decltype(auto)` functions are incomplete with respect to preceding functions in the same class:

```
struct s {
    void f() { a(); } // error: use of ‘auto s::a()’ before deduction of ‘auto’
    auto a() { return 3; }
};
```

This is GCC's complaint; it goes away if the member declarations are reversed. This is because the function definitions are processed in order of declaration, when the `}` from the class definition is reached. If the statement `a();` is processed before the `return 3;`, then the program is ill-formed.