# should return type deduction failure be a substitution failure?

Tags: c++, lambda, auto, sfinae

Based on my test, return type deduction failure seems to be a compile error rather than a substitution failure. The following example gives an error on clang3.4 with -std=c++1y.

```
#include <type_traits>

auto f = [](auto x){return x*2;};

template < typename X, typename=decltype(f(std::declval<X>())) >
std::true_type test_impl(int);

template < typename >
std::false_type test_impl(...);

template < typename T >
using test = decltype(test_impl<T>(0));

struct A{};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   static_assert(not test<A>{},"");
   return 0;
}
```

The error reads:

```
main.cpp:3:29: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('A' and 'int')
auto f = [](auto x){return x*2;};
```

In order get a substitution failure, I had to change `f` to

```
auto f = [](auto x) ->decltype(x*2) {return x*2;};
```

by repeating the return statement in a trailing decltype.

But isn't the point of having auto return type deduction (in both lambdas and normal functions in c++14) is to eliminate code repetition like this?

Does anyone have a better way to work around this?

Thanks.

Comment: *"But isn't the point of having auto return type deduction (in both lambdas and normal functions in c++14) is to eliminate code repetition like this?"* No, IIRC the problem is that you had to instantiate the whole function otherwise just to see if SFINAE applies (and SFINAE applies before overload resolution). IIRC there is a short discussion in the return type deduction proposal.

Comment: See, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17608637 which could have easily be found by searching for "return type deduction SFINAE"

Comment: For a *good* workaround, we might have to wait for Concepts (Lite).

Comment: but even with concepts, we still end up repeating the code when defining the constraint, right?

Comment: With concepts, you should categorize those constraints. You won't need to repeat the code for `[](auto x) { return x*2; }` vs `[](auto x) { return x*5; }` but rather write a concept/constraint that requires *the type can be multiplied with integral types*. I'm not sure about the syntax, maybe it'll be something like `[](IntMultipliable x) { return x*5; }`