# SFINAE on template instantiation error?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, sfinae

What I'm asking is probably impossible, but I'll ask just to be sure. As previously asked and answered in this question: [SFINAE and decltype(auto)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608637/sfinae-and-decltypeauto), functions with an auto return type may not SFINAE, because deduction of the return type causes a template instantiation. During instantiation the compiler will produce an error.

However, maybe someone knows of some crazy trick to turn an instantiation error in one piece of code into a substitution failure in another, and thus induce SFINAE?

Here's a piece of code as an example, that causes an error:

```
#include <utility>

struct no_call_ops { };

struct caller
{
    // Goal is to detect whether a particular Handler type
    // will be ok to pass into caller
    template <typename Handler>
    auto operator() (Handler&& handler, int v)
    {
        handler(3.14);

        while (v--)
        {
            handler("hello world");
        }

        // etc...
        // more calls to handler that I don't want to
        // express in the trailing return type.
    }
};

struct fallback { };

struct tester
{
    // Would be nice if this fails substitution...
    template <typename Caller, typename Handler, typename... Args>
    auto operator() (Caller&& caller, Handler&& handler, Args&&... args)
        -> decltype(caller(handler, std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    { }

    fallback operator() (...) { return fallback{}; }  
};

// want detected_t to be "fallback"
using detected_t = decltype(tester{}(caller{}, no_call_ops{}, 42));
```

Play around with [the code on Godbolt here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B1y+-Wall+-Werror',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4YBcRROgngPgChCBndAJxgnSTAHsB9CAQyigboAcSkBvJAL4BuYmUrUkLNgnKFehJEnQIAtpyjNlqPJwRhmK5AAlmYOFBlFFiaDoQAKZhjoBKJFxma65e2/smzC3IAMmCkAAtTcxkAGiRwdBcFPmTFSMCZewBmADoARgAWFyFFRWSBQmFRCioaADNWKAAjZggAaz5BEVIaiWUyGTlk5TUNLRQ7fUMkAGFG2KVcXSnjKKC4yYMEHJ2kAEFyAHMSKyQndDp3XXIvHz856RCwqXWkAOiniLWFg%2BPQnZyZyOJDcAFp8EgbFA7PYXpl0h84mQ4AAuFF1bwAd2Y5DgKF%2BJ0cwJcAJcSUU/AqZUUDTYLXaV08FzuSHspM65AQ6Bg5DASFpzVabV4wkEZSqhBgJHAh0hXIQ1AQcAYNAAvHLbEsHP1lOQRbD5nqBHF6ExGhxuCK4gUAExkoRAA)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to have happen?   no_call_ops doesn't have a operator(), so trying to call it is an error.  SFINAE only works on the type data of a function/type, not on the code contained.   You could put sfinae on your operator() to amek sure that Handler is callback, but I'm not sure that's what you want.  ... MAYBE

Comment: I guess that's what I'm trying to do, is SFINAE on the code contained. The end result would be that everything compiles, and `detected_t` is the `fallback` type. Hence why I think this might be impossible, because I'm asking the compiler to throw away code that it instantiates.

To further motivate what i'm trying to do, is imagine that handler is called several times, with different types. I don't want to create a trailing return type there because it would be too complicated for me to express.

Comment: Not sure exactly what I did... https://godbolt.org/g/v4Mn5i  but I did use a trailing return type.

Comment: Yep, that works (and you don't even need the `int_t` stuff. My requirement is not to have a trailing return type, and just have auto. I'll change the problem a bit :P

Comment: why no trailing return type?  because your real code is more complicated than the example?   or...  Also, without the int_t stuff, it would break depending on the return type of the Handler (i.e. if it's not an integer type).. I think

Comment: Anyhow, it's absolutely impossible for SFINAE to work on contained code, because the code isn't guaranteed to be available at compile time.

Comment: @xaxxon Yeah, the code is more complicated, and I don't want to manage/sync the trailing return type with the code as it changes. I want a "special" SFINAE auto :P

Comment: Presumably you could make a helper to do that work for you.   Something to take the list of types the handler takes, do the declval instantiation and get the return type for you.  Or just stuff it into a std::function and use the "return type" type in std::function..  Maybe I'll play around with trying to make that.  or maybe http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of

Comment: I tried again with a new answer.. it's a trailing return type, but it's a constant string regardless of Handler's type

Comment: If you're literally trying to understand if the callback accepts the input provided in your code, then I guarantee it cannot.   If you cannot provide that input in the type, then you cannot do what you want.  Because like I said before, the code isn't guaranteed to be available to the compiler

Answer (score 0):

Is this trailing return type acceptable?

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

struct no_call_ops { };

template<class T>
using int_t = int;

struct caller
{
  template <typename Handler, int_t<typename result_of<Handler>::type> = 0>
  auto operator() (Handler&& handler, int) -> typename result_of<Handler>::type
  {
    handler(3.14);    
  }
};


struct fallback { };

struct tester
{
  template <typename Caller, typename Handler, typename... Args>
  auto operator() (Caller&& caller, Handler&& handler, Args&&... args) -> decltype(caller(handler, std::forward<Args>(args)...))
  { }

  fallback operator() (...) { return fallback{}; }  
};

using detected_t = decltype(tester{}(caller{}, no_call_ops{}, 42));
```

Comment: You could try to stuff the handler into a std::function with the appropriate input types to simplify having to do a bunch of declval stuff... or pass in a parameter pack of types and do a declval<Ts>()...

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
#include <utility>

struct no_call_ops { };

struct caller
{
  template <typename Handler, class = decltype( std::declval<Handler>()(3.14) )>
  decltype(auto) operator() (Handler&& handler, int)
  {
    handler(3.14);    
  }
};

struct fallback { };

struct tester
{
  template <typename Caller, typename Handler, typename... Args>
  auto operator() (Caller&& caller, Handler&& handler, Args&&... args) -> decltype(caller(handler, std::forward<Args>(args)...))
  { }

  fallback operator() (...) { return fallback{}; }  
};

using detected_t = decltype(tester{}(caller{}, no_call_ops{}, 42));
```