# Forwarding the Return Value of a Generic Callable Object

Tags: c++, c++11

The code below forwards a parameter pack to some user-defined callable object (in this case, a function pointer). Is there a way in C++11 to return the callable's return value? More specifically, I want to be able to deduce the return type for raise() so that I can add a return statement to it. I realize I could just add a return type template parameter, but should we not already know the return type from the template parameter Func?

```
size_t example(const std::string& str)
{
    return str.size();
}

template <class Func>
class signal
{
public:
    signal()
    {
    }

    ~signal()
    {
    }

    void attach(Func handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    template <typename... T>
    void raise(T&&... args)
    {
        auto val = _handler(std::forward<T>(args)...);
       // How do I return this?
    }

private:
    Func _handler;
};

typedef size_t(*fcn)(const std::string&);

int main()
{
    signal<fcn> sig;
    sig.attach(&example);
    sig.raise("hello!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to use C++14 features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `decltype` was made for.

```
template <typename... T>
auto raise(T&&... args) ->
  decltype(std::declval<Func&>()(std::forward<T>(args)...))
{
    return _handler(std::forward<T>(args)...);
}
```

`decltype(expr)` gives the type of `expr`. Note that you need `args` in there: `Func` could be a functor object with multiple overloaded `operator()` functions with different return types, you'd need the argument types to determine which overload gets used.

Comment: In C++14, you could use `-> decltype(auto)`... Or if you don't care about the reference-ness (i.e you're fine with *copy*), then you could just write `-> auto` .

Comment: @Nawaz `auto raise(...)-> auto {` would be unneccessarily verbose. `auto raise(...) {` would do.

Comment: @anderas: Of course. I just wanted to keep my comment concise, as that is a minor detail.

Comment: @Nawaz Note though: that behaves differently when the `Func` is not callable with the given arguments. It becomes undetectable with SFINAE because the failure would happen outside of substitution.

Comment: @hvd: Yes, that is [an important semantical difference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17608907/415784). Thanks for pointing out that to me.