# std::is_invocable<...> checking for member function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, std

The following code correctly determines when `Writer( t )` can be called for a given `T`.

```
template <typename T>
inline void Process( const T& t )
{
    if constexpr ( std::is_invocable<decltype(Writer), const T&>::value )
    {
        Writer( t );
    }
    else { //... }
}
```

But I can only get this to work for `operator()` defined in Writer as e.g.

```
class Writer
{
 public:
    operator()( const int& )
    {
        \\...
    }
}
```

How do I get the same check to work for a **member function**, i.e check if that function exists, e.g. for `Write(...)` in

```
class Writer
{
public:
    inline void Write( const int& t )
    {
    }
};

class Archive
{

public:

    template <typename T>
    inline void Process( const T& t )
    {
        //check if Writer can handle T
        if constexpr ( std::is_invocable_v<decltype( ???&Writer::Write??? ), ???, const T&> )
        {
            TheWriter.Write( t );
            std::cout << "found";
        }
        else
        {    
            std::cout << "not found";
        }
    }

    Writer TheWriter;

};
```

Every conceivable combination of `Writer.Write`, `Writer::Write`, `decltype` and `&` that I tried in the `if constexpr` results in a compiler error or even `fatal error C1001`.

This is on Visual Studio 2017 MSVC_1916 with /std:c++17.

Comment: The `Writer.Write( t );` line is also wrong: to the left of a `.` must be an object, not the name of a class. Does that function actually need a `Writer` object, or should it be possible to call it without any `Writer` object existing?

Comment: The `inline` keyword on a template is pretty pointless. Templates already have the same semantics as inline functions (except for explicit specialization and instantiation).

Comment: Sorry, shortened it too much. There is of course a member `Writer Writer` Edited this in.

Comment: And I thought the days of Microsoft messing these things up were long gone... Anyway, in the end, I went for a different - and better overloads+SFINAE solution. These kinds of checks are too brittle anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check for a member function like this:

```
template <typename T>
inline void Process( const T& t )
{
    if constexpr ( std::is_invocable_v<decltype(&Writer::Write), Writer&, T const &> )    
    {
        Writer{}.Write(t);
    }
    else 
    { 
        //... 
    }
}
```

Here's a working [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/pUOApf). Thanks @aschepler for pointing out the mistake in the original snippet.

Comment: This is the variant that seems logical, but results in *fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.* So it is probably correct. ;-)

Comment: I think `std::is_invocable_v<decltype(&Writer::Write), Writer&, const T&>`. A pointer to non-static member function requires an object to call the function on, and `std::invoke` and friends treat this class type/object as though it were the first parameter/argument.

Comment: @DoctorNuu I added aschepler's correction, and a link to a working example.

Comment: My own toy example works with and without `Writer&` See https://godbolt.org/z/3ptza_ The full code however produces the fatal error.

Comment: @DoctorNuu I modified your snippet [slightly](https://godbolt.org/z/vYByT2), and it fails with gcc (as it should), but has a fatal error with MSVC. Perhaps a bug?

Comment: Pretty confusing. Can you get your demo to work on MSVC at all? Note that I have 19.16

Comment: No, I couldn't but this seems to be an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461019/c17-wrapping-callable-using-generic-variadic-lambda) in msvc with is_invocable.

Comment: Hey @cigien! I'm getting this error `reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<decltype(&C<T>::emplace_back), C<T>&, const T&>);`. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @Kostas Could you show a demo? I'm not sure what `C` is in your snippet.

Comment: @cigien https://godbolt.org/z/reE5h9v9x. For reference I'm trying to use this in an enable_if for a container template specialization (`template <template <class...> C, class T> class Coder<C<T>, typename std::enable_if_t<...>> {...};`

Comment: @cigien Poke just in case you missed this. If not, no worries :)

Comment: @Kostas Yeah, this slipped my mind. The issue here is that vector push_back is overloaded, so you can't take its address. You can pick a specific overload and use that https://godbolt.org/z/Y74fGxEnj Note that this is actually UB I think, because you're not allowed to take the address of functions in std (and I presume member functions of std containers). This should work for your own types though.